# drupal_http_request redirect is not a fully qualified uri. Throws missing schema error 1002

Tags: authentication-authorization

I am trying to authorise with an [Viagogo API](http://developer.viagogo.net/documentation/api-security/oauth-authentication-for-public-services) using oauth in my custom module (i have my credentials from Viagogo). I can construct the initial URL OK but the redirect response from the API is a relative reference with an absolute path i.e. /Public/SimpleOAuthAccessRequest/Authorize?oauth_token=Y%34hg5k34jhg5%3D

Which in turn is throwing a missing schema error using [drupal_http_request](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7).

> object(stdClass)#466 (4) { ["error"]=> string(14) "missing schema"
>   ["code"]=> int(-1002) ["redirect_code"]=> string(3) "302"
>   ["redirect_url"]=> string(87)
>   "/Public/SimpleOAuthAccessRequest/Authorize?oauth_token=Y%2Fbm9asdfasdfdsfjJfdd3D"

How can i get around this?

Is there a simpler way my custom module can authorise with oauth and access this API instead of my having to write this connector? The [PHP code sample provided by Viagogo](http://developer.viagogo.net/documentation/code-samples) is using CURL and works fine outside of Drupal but once I bring the functions inside my custom module it doesn't work hence me using drupal_http_request.

Comment: Why not just wrap those API functions in a class and use that instead of `drupal_http_request()`? But if you can't do that for some reason, just prepend the scheme and host to the path you get back from the API  (i.e. qualify it) before you pass it on

Comment: Am i missing something in Drupal that can handle this oauth authentication out of the box @Clive. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Drupal doesn't have anything, no...I had a quick look at the API code and if it was me I'd just use that directly, rather than trying to use Drupal's API. That's from the vendor, you can be pretty sure it works. Also if the problem's being caused by a redirect that happens inside `drupal_http_request()`, it stands to reason you could only 'fix' it by altering that function

Comment: @Clive as in the sample code they provided? Yes that works fine if i run it as a file outside of Drupal (in root) but ideally i want it inside a custom module. Once i bring their sample code inside my custom module CURL refuses to return anything.

Comment: Drupal doesn't get involved with curl at all, it doesn't really make sense that the code would work on the same server, but not when it's in a .module file (which after all is just included and processed like any other PHP file). I don't think `drupal_http_request` is an option if it doesn't like the redirect path it's given, so you're left with either altering that function so it does like the path, or implementing it manually. If you're going manually the code right from the vendor would be best

Comment: ...it's working inside my Drupal module now too (using the vendor code *embarassed face)...i was var_dumping to see the results coming off the API but because of the redirect i was missing them and hence thinking it wasn't working. It's all dumped out for all to see when it's run as the stand alone file in root.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to dump out the results coming back from my API call one step too early  and before the redirect (to present the token) had taken place so inside Drupal it didn't appear as if anything was happening.